# Use Typhoon to inject property into class that is not initialised by Typhoon Assembly

Tags: ios, cocoapods, typhoon

I am working on a private pod and currently I have some difficulty using Typhoon to inject property into the bootstrap class.

My class:

```
public class MyLibrary: NSObject {
    var dependency: MyDependencyProtocol?
}
```

My assembly:

```
open class MyLibraryAssembly: TyphoonAssembly {

    open dynamic func lib() -> Any
    {
        return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(MyLibrary.self) { (definition) in
            definition?.injectProperty(#selector(getter: MyLibrary.dependency), with: self.dependency())
            definition?.scope = .singleton
        }
    }
}
```

However, the consumer app will use *var lib = MyLibrary()* to initialise the object rather than using dependency injection. How do I inject dependency into the MyLibrary class when the init is called?

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to define a class method in your `MyLibrary` class to return a build instance of your `MyLibrary` class. This method would:

- [Bootstrap Typhoon](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Quick-Start)
- Ask Typhoon for a built & configured instance of your library
- Return it to the method caller

Example: `MyLibrary.instance()` or `MyLibrary.instanceWithConfig(someConfig)`.

- Callers of these methods won't care how the object is build behind behind the scenes - just trust that a built & configured instance is returned.
- Still the option to assembly an instance of the library manually using the public constructor.